# Div con position:relative superposiciona otro con position:fixed

Tags: css3

Tengo un div "menú de la pagina" con posición  fixed y otro mas abajo con position:relative; que quiero poner un texto en el,pero cuando bajo la pagina el relative se monta con el fixed cuando debería de estar por detrás,que se siguiera viendo el menú aunque baje, ¿que posicionamiento tengo que poner: relative? absolute? otro?

```css
#menu{
position: fixed;
width: 1425px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #8F8177;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
body{
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
}
#menu-botones{
position: fixed;
top: 15px;
left: 120px;
font-size:25px;
}
#menu-botones li{
display: inline;
}
img.logo{
width: 190;
height: 90;
position:fixed;
top: 5px;
left: 900px;
}
img.imagenprincipal{
width: 1351px;
height: 900px;
margin:-10px;
margin-top:92px;
}
a {
    color: #CBC5C0;
}
#segundo {
width: 1351px;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
margin:-10px;
margin-top:0px;
}
#tercero{
background-color: #8F8177;
position:relative;
top:10px;
left:10px;
width: 251px;
height: 50px;   
}
#tercero h1{
margin:0px;
margin-top:0px;
}
#informacion{
background-color: #8F8177;
margin:280px;
margin-top:1030px;
width: 851px;
height: 250px;
}
#acceso{
background-color: #8F8177;
position:relative;
top: 1425px;
left: -10px;
width: 1351px;
height: 250px;
}
div{
display:inline-block:
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
<title>e&f Interiorismo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<div id="menu-botones">
<ul class="modelo">
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="index.php">¿Quienes Somos?</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/proyectos/proyectos.php">Proyectos</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Servicios</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Productos</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://.es-es.facebook.com/E-F-Interiorismo-222489607867994/">Facebook</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/contacto/contacto.php">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<IMG class="logo" SRC="/FOTOS/LOGO.jpg"></img>
<IMG class="imagenprincipal" SRC="/FOTOS/tienda.jpg"></img>
<div id="segundo">
<div id="tercero">
<h1>¿Quienes Somos?</h1>
</div>
<div id="informacion">
</div>
</div>
<div id="acceso">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques preguntas. Si tienes que agregar más información, edita la pregunta original en lugar de crear una nueva. Voy a marcar la otra como duplicada porque ésta tiene más información.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

> La propiedad CSS z-index indica el z-order de un elemento y sus descendientes. Cuando varios elementos se superponen, z-order determina cuales cubren a otros. Un elemento con mayor z-index generalmente cubre a otro menor.

En tu caso:

```
#menu{
position: fixed;
width: 1425px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #8F8177;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index:2;
}
#acceso{
background-color: #8F8177;
position:relative;
top: 1425px;
left: -10px;
width: 1351px;
height: 250px;
z-index:1;
}
```

```css
#menu{
position: fixed;
width: 1425px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #8F8177;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
body{
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
}
#menu-botones{
position: fixed;
top: 15px;
left: 120px;
font-size:25px;
}
#menu-botones li{
display: inline;
}
img.logo{
width: 190;
height: 90;
position:fixed;
top: 5px;
left: 900px;
}
img.imagenprincipal{
width: 1351px;
height: 900px;
margin:-10px;
margin-top:92px;
}
a {
    color: #CBC5C0;
}
#segundo {
width: 1351px;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
margin:-10px;
margin-top:0px;
}
#tercero{
background-color: #8F8177;
position:relative;
top:10px;
left:10px;
width: 251px;
height: 50px;   
}
#tercero h1{
margin:0px;
margin-top:0px;
}
#informacion{
background-color: #8F8177;
margin:280px;
margin-top:1030px;
width: 851px;
height: 250px;
}
#acceso{
background-color: #8F8177;
position:relative;
top: 1425px;
left: -10px;
width: 1351px;
height: 250px;
}
div{
display:inline-block:
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
<title>e&f Interiorismo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<div id="menu-botones">
<ul class="modelo">
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="index.php">¿Quienes Somos?</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/proyectos/proyectos.php">Proyectos</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Servicios</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Productos</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://.es-es.facebook.com/E-F-Interiorismo-222489607867994/">Facebook</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/contacto/contacto.php">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<IMG class="logo" SRC="/FOTOS/LOGO.jpg"></img>
<IMG class="imagenprincipal" SRC="/FOTOS/tienda.jpg"></img>
<div id="segundo">
<div id="tercero">
<h1>¿Quienes Somos?</h1>
</div>
<div id="informacion">
</div>
</div>
<div id="acceso">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias a funcionado, me podrías decir que significa z-index? o lo busco mejor en internet? es por mi caso

Comment: Te puse el enlace a una buena explicación de z-index. Este es: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: tengo que cerrar el tema o algo parecido? gracias por ayudarme

Comment: Creo que simplemente tienes que aceptar la respuesta como válida, así aparecerá en verde. Bienvenido a stackoverflow, si eres nuevo :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones. Una es quitar el posicionamiento relativo establecer la posición del div utilizando el padding del div contenedor.

Otra es establecer un z-index alto al menú para asegurarte de que queda por encima del resto del contenido.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo con la primera opción:

```css
#menu{
position: fixed;
width: 1425px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #8F8177;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
body{
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
}
#menu-botones{
position: fixed;
top: 15px;
left: 120px;
font-size:25px;
}
#menu-botones li{
display: inline;
}
img.logo{
width: 190;
height: 90;
position:fixed;
top: 5px;
left: 900px;
}
img.imagenprincipal{
width: 1351px;
height: 900px;
margin:-10px;
margin-top:92px;
}
a {
    color: #CBC5C0;
}
#segundo {
width: 1351px;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
margin:-10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
#tercero{
background-color: #8F8177;
width: 251px;
height: 50px;   
}
#tercero h1{
margin:0px;
margin-top:0px;
}
#informacion{
background-color: #8F8177;
margin:280px;
margin-top:1030px;
width: 851px;
height: 250px;
}
#acceso{
background-color: #8F8177;
position:relative;
top: 1425px;
left: -10px;
width: 1351px;
height: 250px;
}
div{
display:inline-block:
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
<title>e&f Interiorismo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<div id="menu-botones">
<ul class="modelo">
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="index.php">¿Quienes Somos?</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/proyectos/proyectos.php">Proyectos</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Servicios</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Productos</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://.es-es.facebook.com/E-F-Interiorismo-222489607867994/">Facebook</a></li>
<li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/contacto/contacto.php">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<IMG class="logo" SRC="/FOTOS/LOGO.jpg"></img>
<IMG class="imagenprincipal" SRC="/FOTOS/tienda.jpg"></img>
<div id="segundo">
<div id="tercero">
<h1>¿Quienes Somos?</h1>
</div>
<div id="informacion">
</div>
</div>
<div id="acceso">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```